# Laravel 3: Is there a way to create an Eloquent model for your many-to-many pivot table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

What I'm looking to do is add in a relation to my pivot table. I have a unique scenario where my pivot table needs it's own has_one relation on the roles table. Does anybody see a problem with creating an Eloquent model specifically for the pivot table? Also, if I was to create this model, is there any way that I could have the following return the model?

```
$user = User::where('id', '=', 1);
$pivot = $user->hasmanyexample()->pivot();
```

I'd specifically like to be able to do the following:

```
$user = User::where('id', '=', 1);
$pivot = $user->example()->pivot();

// class Example_User 
// public function role() { return $this->has_one('Role', 'role_id'); }
$role = $pivot->role();
```

Answer (score 4):

first you have to make a Model of the Pivot, in my case I had a 3 models

- **Edition->has_many_and_belongs_to('Format);**
- **Format->has_many_and_belongs_to('Edition);**

the pivot table generated would be called edition_format, when I made the model you first have to create a directory Edition and in that folder create a file called format.php so you would have the following:

**-application/models/Edition/format.php**

then you have to change the table name, because laravel looks for the plural (edition_formats)  and the relation needs edition_format, so you have to to the following, add:

```
class Edition_format extends Eloquent
```

{

```
public static $table = "edition_format";


/* whatever you want */
```

}

Then you can call it like so: Edition_format::find(1);